# Spring / Hibernate application hangs during initialization

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

The web application deploys in other systems. but, it just hangs in my system.

- Java Version: jdk1.8
- TomcatVersion: apache-tomcat-7.0.63
- Spring Version:4.1.6.RELEASE
- Hibernate Version:4.3.5.Final
- MySQL connector:5.0.8.bin jar

Please see the logs below.

**Logs**

```
[org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] : [MySQL5] -> [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect] (replacing [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect])
[2014-01-14 13:44:25,537 main] [org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl : 79] [DEBUG] Registering named strategy selector [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] : [MySQL5InnoDB] -> [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect] (replacing [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect])
[2014-01-14 13:44:25,609 main] [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration : 1841] [DEBUG] Preparing to build session factory with filters : {}
[2014-01-14 13:44:25,611 main] [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration : 1841] [DEBUG] Preparing to build session factory with filters : {}
```

The deployment just hangs like a sleeping thread after this line. What might the problem? Please let me know if you need more information

**EDIT 1 :**
I have configured the hibernate sessionfactory via Spring dependency injection. Please check below

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mobile_recharge"/>
    <property name="username" value="keerthi" />
    <property name="password" value="keerthi" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="-1"></property>
    <property name="maxActive" value="-1"></property>
    <property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="-1"></property>
    <property name="maxWait" value="30000"></property>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"></property>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ciar.mobilerecharge.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="use_sql_comments">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: You can show the file  db.properties  ?

Comment: @Saahon Please check the edit. thanks

Comment: The problem was with my installation of tomcat 7.0.63. When i tried to deploy the application in another tomcat instance in a different machine. It worked. Might be class path problems in the environment. I couldn't still find the root cause of it.